# Powerapps : datasource result in text field

Tags: powerapps

My question is : how to find and write my title where ID is max.
I want something like that : Filter(Budget2.ID;Max(ID))

And second question : I can't use Filter with a text field. How can I write my title in the text field ?

I have : 
ID       Name
1        TOTO01
2        TOTO02
3        TOTO03

I want my formula to give me : TOTO03 as a result, in a text field.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want something like the expression below:

```
LookUp(
    Budget2;
    ID = Max(Budget2; ID);
    Title)
```

[Filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-filter-lookup) will return you a table (list of items), so you cannot use it directly in a label / text field. [LookUp](https://learn.microsoft.com/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-filter-lookup) will return a single record, and if you use the third argument (column name) it will extract the value for that column.

The expression above is looking for a single record, where the ID is the maximum id for that table, and extracting the `Title` column from it.